# Multiple Tag Search WordPress

Tags: wordpress, search, tags

Wordpress 3.5.2.
Old construction like

```
?tag=tag1+tag2
```

doesn't work any more. i dunno why.
I have a form with check boxes. And tags which sorts by category.
So i wanna search by

```
tag1+tag2+tag3
```

in specific category.
How to do that?
I'm tired look for a solution :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comma separate them:

```
/** posts with any of the following tags */   
$query = new WP_Query( 'tag=bread,baking' );

/** posts with all of the following tags */
$query = new WP_Query( 'tag=bread+baking+recipe' );

/** or alternatively */
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag_slug__in' => array( 'bread', 'baking' ) ) );
```

Documented here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query